# Continuity of a linear functional for sequences of projections

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces

Let $T_+$ be the set of a positive trace-class operators over some separable Hilbert space and
$A: T_+ \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ some linear functional.

In general, $A$ will not be continuous. However,  I'm interested in the following weak type of continuity of $A$: for any sequence $\{P_n\}$ of commuting and increasing projection operators ($P_n P_m = P_m P_n$, and $P_n \ge P_m$ if $n\ge m$) that converge to the identity,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} A(P_n \rho P_n) = A(\rho) \qquad \forall \rho \in T_+.$$

For example, the von Neumann entropy $A(\rho):=\mathrm{tr}\{-\rho \ln \rho\}$ is a functional (albeit a nonlinear one) that obeys this kind of continuity (Wehrl, 1978), although generally it is not continuous (only lower semi-continuous) in the trace-norm.

Is there a name for this weaker kind of continuity?  Are there simple characterization of the class of functionals that obey it?